# can spark access remote mysql DB .Assume Remote server do not have spark and can spark acces DB view

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I need to use mysql Data to process by spark. Can spark able to process remote mysql data . Think like that I install spark on servre A and mysql is on server B.
Server B do not have spark,mysql is installed on it . So is it possible using spark from server A , we  process mysql data on server B .

Also second query , let say , I have complex query in database, so I created view on it , can spark take data based on that view ?

Thanks in advance 
Debashis Mallick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not have spark installed on same server as MySQL . You can read data from MySQL from server A to Spark in Server B using sqoop ( jdbc driver) and process the data in Server B ( Spark Cluster ) .

Regd second query , the answer is yes . Again you can use sqoop to read data from the view on mySQL data .
Note : Sqoop is currently not supporting import from view in direct mode. Use JDBC based (non direct) mode in case that you need to import view (simply omit --direct parameter).
Reference : 
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html